# How do I deal with the camera?

Tags: xenoblade-chronicles-x

I've just started playing *Xenoblade Chronicles X*, and I noticed how *different* the camera behaves compared to other games.

Whenever I press the right analog stick, the camera takes a (short) while before moving. When I let go of it, the camera takes another (short) while before stopping. In other words, the camera accelerates.

Since I'm used to cameras that *don't* accelerate, i.e. react directly to my input, I have a hard time controlling it. I've already increased the horizontal movement speed of the camera (which I felt is way too slow by default), but I can't find an option to turn off the acceleration.

What option do I need to change if I want the camera to behave the way I expect?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change the Manual Camera Tracking Speed (2nd option in camera setting) to the right and the acceleration will stop.

Comment: I never thought they'd call it "tracking". Thanks!

Comment: No problem! Btw on areas where the cam is fixed like inside the barracks or near a terminal, the cam will still be on acceleration, once you move away it'll be like you've set it again. Enjoy!